# QGis - Multiple vectors into mulptiple rasters

Tags: qgis, batch, rasterization

I have a list of 50 vectors I need to rasterize on QGIS. Would you know if it is possible or if there is any script to run them in only one batch or do I need to do the vector>raster process to each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "batch" them by clicking here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

But when doing it in batches how to control the naming of the output? I would like it to have the same reference of the input vector.